# Using FOR XML AUTO against a synonym

Tags: sql-server-2005, synonym, for-xml

We've just switched to synonyms for linked server stuff, and noticed that our FOR XML output is no longer correct.  When returning XML results from a view, we could alias the view and that would be assigned as the element name.  With synonyms, however, it seems to ignore the alias?  We're still mostly on SQL 2005 - this bug doesn't seem to happen on our 2008 instance.  Is this a known problem, and any ideas for work-arounds?

For example, this is what we used to be able to do:

```
select top 3 number from Numbers as elementname for xml auto

<elementname number="0"/><elementname number="1"/><elementname number="2"/>
```

And this is what happens with a synonym:

```
select top 3 number from Numbers_synonym as elementname for xml auto 

<dbo.Numbers number="0"/><dbo.Numbers number="1"/><dbo.Numbers number="2"/>
```

As you can see, SQL Server seems to use the name of the actual referenced object instead of the alias.  This gets worse for cross server queries, because you get the four-part name instead of the nice alias.  (eg: `<rick_server.rick_database.dbo.Numbers number="0"/>`...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes `FOR XML AUTO` does the "wrong thing" - you can control the XML element name if you use the fractionally more verbose:

```
SELECT TOP 3 number
FROM Numbers_synonym
FOR XML PATH('elementname'), TYPE
```

Comment: I'm not working at that company anymore (this question is 7 months old), so I can't check it directly.  How would you use XML PATH() with a multi-table select (eg: two inner joined synonyms)?  With aliased tables, the aliases are used as the nested element names.  How would XML PATH resolve which path to apply to which synonym?

Comment: @Rick Depends on your query - you could use a correlated query with a `FOR XML PATH` clause, which would allow it.